# Python files not working proprely as modules (Just in VS code maybe?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-module

Before I show you the problem, I will give a simple example here:
(Please consider reading the whole problem and the important notes)

-Main folder: contains:
+main.py
+Extern modules folder (named ex_modules)

-Extern modules folder: contains:
+module1.py
+module2.py

main.py needs module1.py **AND** module2.py, but module1.py just needs module2.py

So I thought about **importing module2.py into module1.py** and then **import module1.py into the main file**, this is how I proceeded:

module2.py:

```
def module2_function1():
    return something

def module2_function2():
    return something2

def module2_function3():
    return something3
```

module1.py:

```
from module2 import *  #as I said, they are both in the same folder

def module1_function():
    module2_function1()
    module2_function2()
```

main.py:

```
from ex_modules.module1 import *

module1_function() #a module1 function that uses module2 functions
module2_function3() #a module2 function
```

**VS code doesn't show any warnings when working on the main file
but this error occurs when I run it:**

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module2'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\some path xD\Main folder\main.py in <module>
----> 2 from ex_modules.module1 import *
      3 
      4 module1_function()
      5 module2_function3()

c:\some path xD\Main folder\ex_modules\module1.py in <module>
      1 
----> 2 from module2 import *  #as I said, they are both in the same folder
      3 
      4 def module1_function():
      5         module2_function1()

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module2'
```

**This is due to the fact that it imports module2 (that is inside the ex_modules folder) as if it was in the main folder with main.py**

I tried to import both modules in the main file as 'ex_modules.module1 and ex_modules.module2' and yeah, it doesn't work

**The question is:
Is my syntax wrong? Or is this just a VS code bug?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from running in the directory above `ex_modules`. Try changing the import in `module1.py` to a relative import:

```
from .module2 import *
```